# Insert (join of two tables) into a different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables with a bunch of stuff I don't need in them. One has info about a user and the other their password.

I have a new table that will store both their info and password together.

Additionally, the user info table has separate fields for first name and last name and I need to combine them to place them in the "name" column and add a space between them.

I need to do this without disrupting (modifying) either of the old tables.

I also need to be able to add an integer value to the id column.

I would think the basic syntax looks like this, but don't know what to do past here

```
INSERT INTO newtable (id, name, email, password) VALUES ((JOIN statement?), (JOIN statement?), (JOIN statement?), (JOIN statement?))
```

How can I accomplish this with a script?

Old table 1 (`oldtable1`):

```
User ID (id)
Password value (pass)
```

Old table 2 (`oldtable2`):

```
User ID (id)
First name (fname)
Last name (lname)
Email (email)
```

New table (`newtable`):

```
id
name
email
password
```

Comment: Do you have MySQL or MS SQL-Server?

Comment: `SQL-Server` tag is for MS SQL-Server only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, email, password INTO NewTable 
FROM 
(
  SELECT o1.id, CONCAT(o2.fname, ' ', o2.lname), o2.email,  o1.Password
  FROM oldTable1 AS o1
    JOIN oldTable2 AS o2
    ON o1.id = o2.id
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, Password, Name, Email INTO NewTable 
FROM (SELECT ID, Password
FROM oldTable1
FULL OUTER JOIN oldTable2
ON oldTable1.ID=oldTable2.ID)
```

Try that... I'm no genius but it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

IN SQL-Server you can do it this way if `NewTable` not exists yet.

```
SELECT IDENTITY(INT,1,1) id, name,email,password
INTO newtable
FROM oldtable1 ot1
     join oldtable2 ot2 on ot1.UserID=ot2.UserID
```

and if it already exists

```
insert into newtable (name,email,password)
select name,email,password
FROM oldtable1 ot1
         join oldtable2 ot2 on ot1.UserID=ot2.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a new table for join of two tables? Ever heard of views? You can use that.

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT oldtable1.id, oldtable1.pass, oldtable2.fname, oldtable2.email
FROM oldtable1 JOIN oldtable2 ON oldtable1.id = oldtable2.id
```